# Implement text search in eclipse across workspace

Tags: eclipse, text-search

Is there any possibility that I can input a string and the code returns the locations where the string is present by searching across the eclipse workspace?

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The 'Search > Search...' dialog provides this type of search on the 'File Search' tab.

Comment: I agree, but I would like to implement the same in my code by using search API(if available) to develop the plugin further